# how to accomplish the protocol that send the bonus points to specific anonymous users

Tags: cryptography

As the title, Users anonymously register his account from a control center(full trusted).when the users send his data through the anonymous network, how to accomplish the protocol that he will get the  points or awarding if the data below the standard value without leak out his reality identity?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: if you  register a digital account in my supermarket and your consumption amount is over (for example 1000 dollar),how to accomplish a protocol to send a award to your account but without knowing your real identity?

Comment: Are you asking how to have an anonymous account be credited for an otherwise non-anonymous activity?

Comment: @user78791  Please describe the environment more. Do they have sort of club-cards? Can the cashiers give them cards with codes? Etc...

Comment: Oh, thank you, you can see my comment on the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment, I guess that the following is true:

- there is a way for you to have anonymous accounts be registered,
- you seem to have an otherwise not anonymous endeavor, a supermarket for example, where people go shopping themselves or mail order stuff using their name,
- you want people to be able to anonymously get awards for activities that are not taken anonymously.

This is not trivial because there are many side channels.

If your prices are aligned such that you cannot correlate purchases to people by the amount billed, you cold use for example a JWT to sign the amount to be added in the anonymous system.
This will be broken if you can link purchases by amount.

You could, however, track sales by person and give out tokens to be used anonymously when they reached a certain goal.
This, again, will be broken as soon as there is only one active token.

This seems however like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you trying to do in the first place?

There’s also another problem: I assume your users do not trust you to just not track them. Thus, a method would have to be found that makes it impossible for you to track them.

Comment: Recently, i have read a paper about group blind signature, in these paper, the environment  is e-cash, so only if the user doubly use the e-cash ,the central bank can revoke the users' anonymity.Now i want to accomplish a work to reward the user because of his every legal assumption  without revealing his real identity.The first question is the abstract of the problem.

Comment: The problem is just like a paradox.There are many colorful balls in the black box, i think there is hard to find the accurate color ball. So i don't know there is a way to design a protocol in the situation.